# How do I create a row in a table for each user in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `users` and I want to get all users and for each user, create a row in a table called `products`. Is it possible to do this with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the result from a select statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO products (field1,field2...) SELECT 
    something_that_goes_into_products_field1,
    something_that_goes_into_products_field2,
    ....
FROM users
WHERE users_that_have_to_be_inserted
```

If products has an autoincrement field you should probably omit it from the field list.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the respective table structure an [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement should work:

```
INSERT INTO `products`
SELECT 1 FROM `users`
```

In case the products table has one `int`-column, this will insert as much ones as there are users in the `users` table.

You just have to adjust the `SELECT` statement to produce the values you need in your new table.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9049a/1)

Comment: Except, I want to do this for ALL users

Comment: @Shamoon Assuming you have 10 users in `users`, this will add 10 entries of `1` into `products` (assuming no conflicts with uniques ..)

Comment: What if products has different fields?

Comment: @Shamoon Like i said, adjust the `SELECT` statement in a way, that fits your `products` table. You may use constants (like in my example) or some columns of `users`. If you do not want to specify all columns of `products`, use a list of columns like in any other `INSERT` statement.